# Java, MySQL specific query returns nothing

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to select all the distinct values of a single column in a table, however it keeps returning nothing. Things I've checked:

1. Permissions - Account I'm using has permission to do everything
2. Query correct - I'm printing out the query and it works in phpMyAdmin
3. Actually connected  - It's connecting to the correct database because a "SELECT * FROM users" works.
4. Exception - Checked for general exceptions and there weren't any.

Code:

```
public ResultSet execute(String sql) {
    try {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        System.out.println(sql);
        if (stmt.execute(sql)) {
            rs = stmt.getResultSet();
        }
        ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
        int length = meta.getColumnCount();
        System.out.println("Print results");
        while (rs.next()) {
            for (int i=1; i< length; i++) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(i));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("DONE");
        return rs;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("SQL: " + e.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("2: " + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("3: " + e.getErrorCode());
    }
    System.out.println("Nothing found");
    return null;
}
```

The print out:

Connecting to database SELECT `userName` FROM `users` Print results DONE 1

The 1 is the number of columns printed outside of function. Obviously that query doesn't get distinct values, this is just a simpler query I was trying out. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Columns in [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) are indexed starting from 1 and [`getColumnCount`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnCount--) returns the number of selected columns.

As such, you need to replace your for loop to go from 1 to `length` inclusive and not exclusive:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++) { // <-- inclusive here
    System.out.println(rs.getString(i));
}
```